# mysql statement with creating table confusion

Tags: mysql

some help with mysql is appreciated. I'm not sure what the following command does, specifically the line `unique doctype_name (doctype, name))`

```
create table __global_search(
                "doctype" varchar(100),
                "name" varchar({0}),
                title varchar({0}),
                content text,
                route varchar({0}),
                published int not null default 0,
                unique doctype_name (doctype, name))
```

I know it's creating a table but the last line confuses me. Does the table also include two more columns "unique" and "doctype_name" but they have the same content as the column "doctype" and "name" respectively? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `UNIQUE` index on 2 columns `doctype` and `name`.

`doctype_name` is the name of that index.

See the [mySQL docs about how to create a unique index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique)